# Pros and cons of having a central event store for unrelated services

Tags: architecture, event-sourcing, event-driven

Let's say there is a big system that have several areas of concern, users, billing, orders, payments, products/inventory, etc. Each of these areas have services that rely with each other. Worth noting that  each are maintained by different teams.

Does it makes sense to have central event store/ database for events? Where each service can write and read events on.

What are potential pitfalls for this design? When would it be better to have separate event store?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's more about Conway's law:

If your organization is big, has large teams, and cross-service communication is mainly done via events. Then your events likely become a contract (which creates a kind of coupling) and must be understandable and speak a unified language.

That said, it is not straightforward, especially if you are following DDD and your events are initially domain events that speak the subdomain language and may change based on the team's understanding of the context.

A technique I read about is to have an event store per service and  another dedicated event store for cross-service communication, i.e.,
Each service event store projects its domain events in the latter while respecting the contract and the unified spoken language.

Answer (score 0):

All of the issues with having services share a (CRUD-style) database apply to having services share an event store.

In particular, a shared event store will increase the tendency to treat the event store's journals as the point of integration for services, rather than, for instance, have explicit projections/read-models/anti-corruption-layers serve as integration points.  This will increase the level of coupling, which implies that the services and the teams developing them cannot truly be autonomous.

Note that this doesn't imply that you couldn't have all your services share a dependency on a particular common "event store management system" (I use the term in analogy to a DBMS) infrastructure, as long as it's enforced in some way that no service can reach into (even read-only) another service's event journal.  There may be operational benefits to centralizing that infrastructure (e.g. lower infrastructure cost, more ability to treat that infrastructure as mission-critical, etc.)